# How to use tabBar controller in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

```
    import 'dart:ffi';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:whatsapp_clone/chatScreen.dart';
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
      late TabController  _tabcontroller;
      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        _tabcontroller=TabController(length: 4, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
      }
      @override
      void dispose(){
        _tabcontroller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(

          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor:  Color(0xff075E54),
            title: const Text('Whatsapp Clone'),
            actions: [IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
            PopupMenuButton(onSelected: (value){print(value);},
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){return [
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('New Group'),value: 'New Group'),
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('New Broadcast'),value: 'New Broadcast'),
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Whatsapp web'),value: 'Whatsapp web'),
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Starred messages'),value: 'Starred messages'),
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Settings'),value: 'Settings')
            ];
            }
            ),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _tabcontroller,
              tabs: const [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt)),
              Tab(text:'CHAT'),
              Tab(text: 'STATUS'),
              Tab(text: 'CALLS')
              ],
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(controller: _tabcontroller,
          children: const [
            Text('camera'),
            ChatPage(),
            Text('status'),
            Text('calls')
          ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I want to show the chatscreen which is at 1 index, when opening the app, and i have given the initial index to 1 also, but whenever i open my app, although the chat tabbar was selected but the content was showing from first screen. how can i solve this problem

Comment: Can you try rebuilding the app, I've failed to get issue

Comment: might help https://github.com/FlashbadBB/Flutter-Challenges